# Aligning multiple EditTexts and TextViews after a pattern

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, alignment, android-edittext

I want to create a Manage Profile Activity in my app, which fashions a form-like successions of fields as follows:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">

  <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView android:text="EMAIL "/>
    <EditText android:hint="EMAIL "/>
  </LinearLayout

  <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView android:text="USERNAME "/>
    <EditText android:hint="USERNAME "/>
  </LinearLayout

<LinearLayout>
```

I would want all EditTexts to be aligned by a vertical line right after the longest TextView. ( which in this case seems to be "FIRST NAME" )

EMAIL      alex.johnson@mailbox.com

USERNAME   alexton_mg84

FIRST NAME Alex

..

CELL       +44 325 23 523

GENDER     M

..

Here is an attached snippet of what it currently looks like.

[image]

And this is the behaviour I'm after:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is your full code dude add more field as u want :) best of luck

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvOne"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".75"
                    android:text="Email" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/tvThree"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.25"
                    android:text="Three" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="3dp"
                android:background="#000000" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvOned"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".75"
                    android:text="User Name" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/tvThreeda"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.25"
                    android:text="Three" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use layout_weight property to your TextView and EditTexts..

With layout_weight you can specify a size ratio between multiple views. E.g. you have a MapView and a table which should show some additional information to the map. The map should use 3/4 of the screen and table should use 1/4 of the screen. Then you will set the layout_weight of the map to 3 and the layout_weight of the table to 1.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what i would do i the opposite way: two `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="vertical"` in a `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="horizontal"`
The first one for your TextViews, the second one for your EditTexts.

Comment: as I can see, the key words I was looking for were "android:layout_width="0dp", I was using wrap_content. Tyvm!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use layout weights. Here is how you can do > Give a try.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="100" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp" 
        android:text="EMAIL " />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="60"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:hint="EMAIL"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```